# Factoring palindromic polynomial

Tags: factoring, palindromic-polynomials

**Q1. Is every sufficiently large *composite* integer a palindromic number in some non-trivial<sup>‡</sup> base $B$?** The trivial case of $n = 1(n-1) + 1 = (11)_{n-1}$ means it is palindromic in at least one base i.e., $n-1$. This [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493160/can-all-natural-numbers-be-represented-as-palindromes-in-some-base-b) and the sequence [A016038](http://oeis.org/A016038) identifies non-palindromic numbers. In the notes for A016038, we have

> All elements of the sequence greater than 6 are prime $(ab = a(b-1) + a$ or $a^2 = (a-1)^2 + 2(a-1) + 1)$. Mersenne and Fermat primes are not in the sequence.
>
> *Additional comments:* if you can factor a number as $a*b$ then it is a palindrome in base $b-1$, where $b$ is the larger of the two factors. (If the number is a square, then it can be a palindrome in an additional way, in base $(\sqrt{n}-1))$. The $ab$ form does not work when $a = b-1$, but of course there are no two consecutive primes (other than 2,3, which explains the early special cases), so if you can factor a number as $a(a-1)$, then another factorization also exists).

‡: Non-trivial in this question means the base is not $n, n-1, b-1$ as defined in the quoted text above.

**Q2: Is a palindromic number (in some base $B$, non-trivial again) easier to factor than a non-palindromic number?** This [linked article](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath294/kmath294.htm) mentions the following about palindromic polynomials:

> Any palindromic polynomial with real coefficients can be factored into a product of a constant times linear, quadratic, and quartic palindromic polynomials with real coefficients.

Comment: To adress question $2$ : The palindromic property won't make integer factorization easier , unless we have a very special form where the quadratic sieve can be significanly accelerated.

Comment: @Peter: That is interesting. Could you elaborate? I am wondering if there is a non-trivial base $B$ that can force an integer $n$ into that special form.